# How to add alt-text to images attached to model via Cloudinary Active Storage?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cloudinary

I'm working on a project that has_many_photos_attached to a Project model. I'm attaching photos to each new instance of Project via Cloudinary Active Storage in my Seeds like so:

```rb
file = URI.open("URL_TO_PHOTO")
project.photos.attach(io: file, filename: "PHOTO.png", content_type: "image/png")
```

When I want to display the photo(s), I do the following:

```rb
<% @project.photos.each do |photo| %>
    <%= cl_image_tag photo.key %>
<% end %>
```

I want to be sure that my site is accessible, so I want to add 'alt-text' to all my images. However, I'm not sure where this can be done - ideally I would add the alt text when I attach the photo in the seeds.

I'm using Ruby and Ruby on Rails.

Anyone have any ideas?

I've tried adding it simply here:

```rb
<% @project.photos.each do |photo| %>
   <%= cl_image_tag photo.key alt="alt text goes here" %>
<% end %>
```

but received the following error from rails:
`"wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)"`

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
cl_image_tag "sample.png", :width=>100, :height=>100, :alt=>"hello"
```

The above is written in the Repo's example: https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_gem/blob/master/lib/cloudinary/helper.rb#L22

Comment: Thanks so much! So there's no way to add alt-text when I attach the image in seeds?